# JSF on what is UIComponent

Tags: jsf

Iam learning JSF and i need some understanding of

1. what actually is Component Model/framework and
2. what is UIComponent in JSF means and how it is different from a standard HTML element.
3. what it requires to call a component as UIComponent in jSF?

The basic that i know/understood is that any UIComponent is desgined as a class that has its own properties and methods and can connect to managed bean on server independently of other compoenents in page.

Would like to know more on UICompenent,how it is rendered on page and how it reacts to events generated by user actions.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Your question looks like you're looking for an extensive, private tutorial on JSF. Stackoverflow however is about specific programming problems, that after trying you couldn't figure out on your own and may be helpful for others as well (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I would recommend reading one of the many available tutorials online and the official documentation to deepen your knowledge about the topic.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It is good practice here to ask one question per question. 1) is very broad and largely not jsf releated but I'll mark this question as a 'duplicate' of one  2) basically it is: server side counterpart of some simple (plain text input) or complex (datatable) client-side html with events etc. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722635/what-is-the-definition-of-component-in-jsf and 3) nothing specific if you use jsf as intended. No need to create rest things or whatever. JSF does all this for you. Start with a decent modern JSF 2.2 or up tutorial. See https://jsf.zeef.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding JSF as a MVC framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10111387/understanding-jsf-as-a-mvc-framework)